# Conditional detach in many to many relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have 2 models `Tour.php`

```
public function includes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Included');
}
```

`Included.php`

```
public function tours()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tour');
}
```

I'm trying to detach `includeds` if a `tour` has `includeds` in it while deleting a a tour.

Below code is what I have tried:

```
    public function destroy($id)
{
    $tour = Tour::find($id);

    if ($test = $tour->includeds()->count() != null) {
        $tour->includeds()->detach();
    }
    if ($test = $tour->excludeds()->count() != null) {
        $tour->excludeds()->detach();
    }        
    $tour->delete();

    Session::flash('success', 'The tour is sucessfully deleted.');
    return redirect()->route('tours.index');
}
```

The above code is generating `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::includeds()` error. Please point out my mistake that i'm making.

Comment: error means there "includeds" function not found in tour model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small Typo

Try with below codes

```
 public function destroy($id)
  {
    $tour = Tour::find($id);

    if ($test = $tour->includes()->count() != null) {
        $tour->includes()->detach();
    }
    if ($test = $tour->excludeds()->count() != null) {
        $tour->excludeds()->detach();
    }        
    $tour->delete();

    Session::flash('success', 'The tour is successfully deleted.');
    return redirect()->route('tours.index');
}
```